# Do the ring of smooth functions on $\Bbb R$ form an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

> Do the ring of smooth functions on the set of real numbers $\Bbb R$ with the usual pointwise addition and multiplication form an integral domain?

I have been trying to prove this result without any success.Can anyone please help me?Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you heard of bump functions?

Comment: Yes,I have heard about that

Comment: Good. Can you see how they are relevant?

Comment: Yes,I was trying to construct counterexamples using that.

Comment: I'm guessing you intend multiplication and addition to be defined *point-wise* on these function. But you should state that - there probably are *other* definitions for these operations (especially for multiplication) which change the answer to your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could construct two smooth functions $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=0\Leftrightarrow x\notin (0,1) \\
g(x)&=0\Leftrightarrow x\notin (2,3)
\end{align*}
then $f$ and $g$ would be two nonzero elements whose product is zero. The problem now is to find two such functions. Here's a hint on how to do so:

Can you show that the function $\varphi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by
$$
\varphi(x)=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right) & -1<x<1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is smooth and nonzero only on the interval $(-1,1)$? Given that this function has this property, can you use it to define $f$ and $g$?

Comment: So,if I take f(x)=exp(1/x(x-1)),0<x<1 and 0 otherwise;g(x)=exp(1/(x-2)(x-3)),2<x<3 and 0 otherwise then fg=0 on R and both f,g are smooth.Isn't it?